# Run userscript within the IE web browser control in a MFC application

Tags: c++, scripting, mfc, webbrowser-control

I am developing a C++ application using the Internet Explorer webcontrol. I would like to use some userscripts to modify the webpage.

Do you have ideas how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `IHTMLWindow2::execScript()`.